# Harmonic map heat flow in positive curvature

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, curves-and-surfaces, surfaces, harmonic-functions

Suppose I wish to relax/smooth a map $\phi:M\rightarrow N$ between two surfaces $M,N$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  I could try flowing the map using harmonic heat flow, which (as I understand it) is essentially gradient flow on
$$E(\phi):=\int_M\|d\phi\|^2\,dA(M).$$
Eells/Sampson show that this flow converges to a harmonic map when $N$ has non-positive curvature.

I understand that when $N$ is a generic surface, harmonic heat flow can go wrong, e.g. forming "bubbling" artifacts.  I'm wondering:

- For short time, does the harmonic heat flow smooth out a map even if it can reach singularities later on?
- Is there a way to regularize harmonic map heat flow (e.g. smoothing the tension field) to avoid these singularities, potentially at the cost of converging to a non-harmonic map?

Thanks!

Comment: If you just  need to smooth, you can apply a convolution with a reasonable kernel (cheap and easy).

Comment: Yes, the harmonic map heat flow does smooth the metric for short time. The challenge is to find a useful lower bound of the time for which the flow exists in terms of geometric invariants of the manifolds.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  Do you have any references that describe this behavior?